# CKeditor 5: How to up/down cast nested dynamic ul > li elements to model - view structure

Tags: ckeditor5

hopefully some one can assist me for this request which I have been working on for a week and still cant figure it out.
I am trying to migrate a CKeditor 4 plugin to CKeditor 5 which HTML structure is like this below

```
<div class='on-this-page'>
 <h2 class='on-this-page-title'>xxxx<h2>
 <div class='on-this-page-content'>
  <ul>
    <li>heading 1</li>
    <li>heading 2</li>
    ...
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CKeditor 4 version

```
WIDGETS[3] = {
    "details": {
      'name': 'On this page (Section)',
      'label': 'On this page (Section)',
      'description': 'Add on this page section with dynamic links'
    },
    "widget_definition": {
      button: Drupal.t('Bootstrap Widgets'),

      template: '<div class="on-this-page"><h2 class="on-this-page-title">' + title + '</h2><div class="on-this-page-content">' + h2_list.innerHTML + '</div></div>',

      editables: {
        title: {
          selector: '.on-this-page-title'
        },
        content: {
          selector: '.on-this-page-content',
          allowedContent: 'ul; li; a[*];'
        }
      },

      upcast: function (element) {
        return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass('on-this-page');
      }
    }
};
```

Basically a div parent element, a h2 header and a div child element which has dynamic ul li elements generated from custom function according to the h2 heading content of the editor.

I did created model schema like this below

```
schema.register('onThisPage', {
      isObject: true,
      allowWhere: '$block',
});

schema.register('onThisPageTitle', {
      isLimit: true,
      allowIn: 'onThisPage',
      allowContentOf: '$root',
});

schema.register('onThisPageContent', {
      isLimit: true,
      isObject: true,
      allowIn: 'onThisPage',
      allowContentOf: '$root',
});
```

Also create down cast converter by using UI element like this below

```
conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToElement({
      model: 'onThisPageContent',
      view: ( modelElement, { writer } ) => {
        const div = writer.createUIElement( 'div', { class: 'on-this-page-content' }, function( domDocument ) {
          const domElement = this.toDomElement( domDocument );

          domElement.innerHTML = getAllH2Element().outerHTML;

          return domElement;
        } );

        return div;
      }
});
```

The **getAllH2Element()** function is just return a array object with below html

```
<ul>
 <li>xx</li> 
 <li>xx</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

It works first time when I call the command and insert the template but after I save the content and re-open it again. It never work. Mostly like I feel it's the upcast converter. I dont know how to convert the nested parent child elements from model to view. it always gives error like **view-writer-cannot-break-ui-element** when I use **elementToElement** function or ***conversion-slot-filter-incomplete*** with the **elementToStructure** function. I tried to change either upcast, downcast or editingDowncast and never make it work. Also tried dispatcher and slot, never work again.

So my question are

1. How to convert the dynamic ul li elements? As the number of li elements is not fixed, can be 1 or 2 or many, can I just make it all as a template and insert it into the model element?
2. Which conversion API is the best to fetch the custom function like getAllH2Element() to update the element HTML content?
3. If conversion API is not the place to call, where should I call it? I tried to call it in model.change(write) and insert it but it will overwrite the whole structure, even the parent element is missing

If some one can help me, will be every appreciated.

I am trying to convert he CKeditor 4 plugin to CKeditor 5 version